How can I restore Visual Studio Code original workspace layout, i.e., Terminal panel height?
I like to have my windows' settings pristine. The Terminal panel, however, retains the last window settings when re-opened. This is cumbersome when I closed the last VS Code session with the Terminal panel height maximised while I was focussed in doing some Terminal related activity.
When I close VS Code and re-open the application, I'd like the Terminal panel to open with the original height settings VS Code came with when it was installed, not the one I left my previous VS Code session with.
How can I do that?

please clarify your question. do you want the maximized state to be remembered? or a non-maximized state with a specific height to be restored? or both cases?

The other question very much resembles mine. Yet the question title was inaccurate, so I didn't find it.
